# HTML5 Background Video does not autoplay in Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I have an autoplay background video that doesn't play when the page loads in Microsoft Edge. The poster is loaded instead. As soon as you click refresh it then starts playing.

The autoplay works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

The url is: www.obel-logistik.com

I have un-minified the source for this question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to have fixed itself in one of the later updates to the Edge Browser...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in later versions of Microsoft Edge browser.